"Go to Definition" not working in Neovim in Golang's tests
"Go to definition" is working fine in normal code base, but it's just not working in tests. Here's the error message:
Error when executing textDocument/Definition : no package metadata for file file://.....

I'm using vim-lspconfig and mason.nvim.
Any pointers?

Could you give us some details about how your configuration is set up? What language server is throwing this error?

@Cogwizzle I basically use lazyVim's starter template here without much changes: https://github.com/LazyVim/starter
I enabled the lang.go in LazyExtras like this "lazyvim.plugins.extras.lang.go"
http://www.lazyvim.org/extras/lang/go is the documentation for go.

Do you by chance see any language server when you run :LspInfo in one of the test buffers that you're having trouble with?

@Cogwizzle Thanks. :LspInfo gives me three clients: null-ls, copilot, gopls. so it's the gopls for Go. and the cmd location is under mason: cmd:             ~/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/gopls
